# Legendre expansion of the Dirac delta function

Tags: dirac-delta, legendre-polynomials, numerical-calculus

There is a known expansion for the Dirac delta function in terms of the Legendre polynomials as

$\delta(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^k \frac{(4k + 1) (2k)!}{2^{2k + 1} (k!)^2} P_{2k}(x)$.

I would like to verify this identity numerically. We know that $\delta(1) = 0$, so inserting $x = 0$ in the right-hand side of the above must result in zero. If we add the first two hundreds of the terms in the sum using *Mathematica*, results in $7.994$. We expect as we add more terms, the value of the sum decreases and approaches zero, however, for the first three hundreds terms, we obtain $9.784$; and it becomes larger as we add more terms. How will this series approach zero for an infinite number of terms?

Comment: I think the radius of convergence is $1$, and divergence at the end-points can occur. Also, Legendre-polynomials are orthogonal and complete in $L^2[-1, 1]$, so you can expect only $L^2$ convergence (and strictly speaking, $\delta$ is not even an $L^2$ function).

Comment: @Botond Thanks for your comment; I forgot this fact. Also, I do not understand the _Mathematica_'s behaviour. As we increase the number of terms, the value of the sum increases (as you justified it), however, by setting the number of terms to infinity, it returns 0: N[Sum[(-1)^ k (4 k + 1) (2 k)! LegendreP[2 k, 1] / (2^(2 k + 1) k! k!), {k, 0, Infinity}]].

Comment: Can you check it for other, smaller value(s) too?

Comment: Dirac delta is *not* a function. Your equation only makes sense if you multiply it by a function and integrate.